# eclipse plugin setBounds attribute not working

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am developing an eclipse plugin wherein I wanted to show a label and a progress bar.But unfortunately I am unable to change their size.Whatever size I mention in setBounds attribute of label and progressBar,gives me the coordinates:Rectangle {3, 3, 70, 15} and Rectangle {3, 21, 170, 17}

Below is my handler code:

```
private ProgressBar progressBar;
@Override
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

        Display display = Display.getDefault();

        Shell p_shell = new Shell(display,SWT.DIALOG_TRIM);

        p_shell.setText("Translating..");

        p_shell.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

        p_shell.setSize(250, 70);

        Label label = new Label(p_shell, SWT.NONE);

        label.setBounds(10, 20, 180, 20);
        //LINE 101 gives Rectangle {3, 3, 70, 15}

        label.setText("Please wait ...");

        progressBar = new ProgressBar(p_shell, SWT.SMOOTH);

        //progressBar.setBounds(10, 50, 200, 20);
        //LINE 100 gives Rectangle {3, 21, 170, 17}

        progressBar.setBounds(new Rectangle(5, 30, 150, 10));
        //LINE 100 gives Rectangle {3, 21, 170, 17}         

        progressBar.setMinimum(30);

        progressBar.setMaximum(100);

        p_shell.open();

        System.out.println("progress bar  ==> " + progressBar.getBounds());//LINE 100

        System.out.println("label ==> " + label.getBounds());//LINE 101


        while(!p_shell.isDisposed()){

            if(!display.readAndDispatch()){
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        }
```

I am unable to proceed further.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: null your setLayout. but it is not a Good Practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix a Layout with setBounds - the layout will override the bounds. If you remove the `setLayout` the bounds will work.

However using `setBounds` is likely to give you problems on different screens so you should try and make this work using layouts with no setBounds.

Also note that Eclipse wizards, Jobs and other things already provide standard progress indicators.

Comment: Thank you..Its working now.But I have a doubt.How to make a plugin UI independent of screen size?

Comment: Like I said use Layouts - [Understanding Layouts](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm). Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem.